# How to test rails_admin actions in any ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rails-admin

I have a hotel.rb file. I used RSpec to test validations, associations and other actions, but how do I test the rails_admin block? Any sample code will be really appreciated.

```
    class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base

        belongs_to :city

        validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :city_id

        # how do I test this?
        rails_admin do
            visible false
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the abstract model, that the rails admin is using, and read the config from it.

Small example for Rspec:

```
subject { RailsAdmin::AbstractModel.new('Hotel') }

it 'is invisible for rails admin' do
  expect(subject.config.hidden?).to eql true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't have to test functionality that other gems provide. It's the responsibility of the authors of that Gem.

Is there any specific reason you want to test this?

Comment: I do not know why (new programmer). But, I have been suggested to use Cucumber. Any clue how I should proceed?

Comment: For starters, only focus on testing your own code. If you create a class (say Hotel) and add functionality of your own, then add a test for it. I would not recommend starting with cucumber if you're not already familiair with rails testing. The ruby on rails testing guide is the best place to start http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: I am comfortable with RSpec. However, I could not find any tutorial regarding how Cucumber can be used to test rails_admin actions